# PHP: file() and in_array()

Tags: php

after a long time, I try to script something and it don't realy work :D

I have a php script and an external plain text file. With the functions `file()` I load the content of the text file into the php script as an array.

So far so good, next step is to compare a var in the script with the content of the array via the function `in_array()`.

The "static" version looks like this

```
$fruits = array("banana", "pear", "cherry", "apple", "orange");
$fruit = "apple";

if(in_array($fruits, $fruit)) {

echo "Healthy :D";

}
```

and it works. The "dynamic" one, with the external file, looks at the moment like this:

```
$fruits = file('fruits.txt');
$fruit = "apple";

if(in_array($fruits, $fruit)) {

echo "Healthy :D";

}
```

I think I miss something, but what, my PHP skill is not good, just playing around :/ One problem is a whitespace after each item.

The text file looks like this:

```
banana
pear
cherry
apple
orange
```

I hope you can help me and teach me the solution :) thx

Comment: From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php): "Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used, so you still need to use rtrim() if you do not want the line ending present."

Comment: You have the `in_array()` arguments backwards for one (needle, haystack).  Also try using `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` with `file()`.

Comment: @PatrickQ to simple, this is the solution :D thank you, I must be more patient and read all infos in the docs, sorry.